# pod setup failed with "Insecure world writable dir"waring and "RPC failed" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

This is my first time to use CocoaPods.I have ran `sudo gem install cocoapods` successfully,but when I ran 
`pod setup`
,I got the waring and error

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:55: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
[!] Pod::Executable clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: early EOF

fatal: index-pack failed
```

My computer system is OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.
Try the solution from below website.

http://edmondscommerce.github.io/git/during-git-pull-error-rpc-failed-result56-http-code-200-x-kibs-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly.html